# Existence of an Image Resource

Tags: android

For example I have an image named 'Jayson', how do I check if that image is existing or missing on my app's resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do something like this:

```
boolean imageExists;

int exists = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("Jayson", "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());

if (exists != 0) imageExists = true;
else imageExists = false;
```

For more information you can see the developer reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html

Hope this helps

Comment: wow. thank you! Since a non-existing resource returns 0. :) Thanks again.